# How to Update Guava for Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, guava

I'm currently using Selenium 3.0.1 and I have just updated to selenium 3.11.0 and I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.create(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiter;

As I found out, I need to update guava, and my project isn't maven. I already found the old guava jar located at .p2/pool/plugins. 
How can I update Guava through eclipse becuase I can't do it manually

Comment: Where and how did you find out it's a guava issue?

Comment: I have guava 18.0 which doesn't include this method and Guava 22+ has this method in it according to its javadoc

Answer (score 0):

Go to maven repository of guava- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava

Click on the version you want. Click on the **bundle** link to download jar.

Comment: Already Downloaded and tried to add it through "Referenced Libraries" and it didnt work. How to update the jar file inside .p2 folder?

Comment: Do you know how to do it?